# how to update a database row when user session expires, using java?

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

using java how to update a database row when user session expires?
this situation includes
1.user does not click any logout button
2.if automatically browser closed.
3.system directly power-off condition.

so, in these situations how can update a DB row.now iam using following code at logout click condion

```
Connection con = (Connection) new DB2Connection().getDatabaseConnection();
if(request.getParameter("flrmdn") != null)
{
String s1=request.getParameter("flrcaf");
String s2=request.getParameter("flrmdn");

String sql1="update table2 set FLRReference=0 where CAF='"+s1+"' and       MDN='"+s2+"' and FLRReference=1 ";
Statement st1=con.createStatement();
int vupdate=st1.executeUpdate(sql1);
}
else if(request.getParameter("indexmdn") != null)
{
String indexcaf=request.getParameter("indexcaf");
String indexmdn=request.getParameter("indexmdn");

String sql="update table set IndexReference=0 where CAF='"+indexcaf+"' and MDN='"+indexmdn+"' and IndexReference=1 ";
Statement st=con.createStatement();
int entryrows=st.executeUpdate(sql);
}


// Redirecting user to actual required page

if(request.getParameter("location").equalsIgnoreCase("login"))
{
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?logout=true");
}
```

i have used httpsessionlistner(), sessioncreated(),sessiondistroyed() but in that sessioncreated is called automatically but sessiondistroyed is not called whenever session expires

Comment: How do you know that sessionDestroyed() is not called?

Comment: i have used a console msg for both sessioncreated and sessiondistroyed..but sessioncreated msg is printed evry time,wen a new login happen but the same time sessiondistroyed does nt printed the System.out.println message, (which is used inside sessiondistroyed.)

Answer (score 0):

Force session invalidation using [HttpSession.invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) and you can see that the sys out is printed or wait for the session to auto-expire by specifying as shown below in web.xml.

```
<session-config>
      <session-timeout>5</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

Comment: how to update a database row when user session expires? i have wrote HttpSession.invalidate(), but if browser directly close whats the situation, its not calling....

Comment: @Praveen - and that is why you configure auto expiry in web.xml

Comment: k k now it is set to default(30 mins)..but when i tried to close browser directly..corresponding working row on db is not updating..i mean that row is updated to 1 to lock for that user, if that user not fulfill the row and didn't click logout button, that row should assigned to immediate other user. i.e should be '0'

Comment: This will not work when user closes the browser. You need to ask user to Logout or handle it in some other way.

Comment: "This will not work when user closes the browser" is my original question asked here......but you replied about session expiry..thanks anyway